# Rubymotion and Pointers to Structs

Tags: ios, ruby, rubymotion

I'm experimenting with cocosmotion, a Rubymotion implementation of Cocos2d. In the tutorial I'm working through, I have a method that takes a struct as an argument. I consulted the Rubymotion and MacRuby docs, but can't figure out how to instantiate a new object based on the struct I need. I think the main issue is that the struct starts with a lowercase letter and Ruby thinks it's a local variable when I try to work with it.

I believe I have the same problem as stated here:
https://github.com/MacRuby/MacRuby/issues/121

Is there a solution or workaround?

The struct is defined in Objective-C like so:

```
 typedef struct _ccTexParams {
         GLuint  minFilter;
         GLuint  magFilter;
         GLuint  wrapS;
         GLuint  wrapT;
 } ccTexParams;
```

The method I'm trying to call expects a ccTexParams struct.

Here is what I've tried:

```
            @mysprite = Pointer.new("{ccTexParams=
            {GLUint=GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR}
            {GLUint=GL_LINEAR}
            {GLUint=GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE}
            {GLUint=GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE}}", 4)
```

When I try it this way:

```
        @mysprite = Pointer.new(:object, 4)

        @mysprite[0] = GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR 
        @mysprite[1] = GL_LINEAR
        @mysprite[2] = GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
        @mysprite[3] = GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
```

The runtime error is:

```
expected instance of Pointer of type `{_ccTexParams=IIII}', got `@' (TypeError)
```

I also tried:

```
@mysprite = Pointer.new("_ccTexParams", 4)

        @mysprite[0] = GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR 
        @mysprite[1] = GL_LINEAR
        @mysprite[2] = GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
        @mysprite[3] = GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
```

The error:

```
Can't find pointer description for type `_ccTexParams'
```

I've also tried to replace it as CcTexParams, _ccTexParams, and just ccTexParams in a bunch of different ways, no versions of it work.

I tried this:

```
@mysprite = CcTexParams.new
@mysprite.minFilter = GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR 
@mysprite.magFilter = GL_LINEAR
@mysprite.wrapS = GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
@mysprite.wrapT = GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
```

RubyMotion complains it `expected an instance of Pointer, got '#<CcTexParams minFilter=9987 magFilter=9729 wrapS=33071 wrapT=33071>' (CcTexParams) (TypeError)`

I tried just passing `[GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE]` directly to the method.  It complains that it `expected a Pointer but got an Array`.

Perhaps I should just rename `ccTexParams` in the lib to something like `CCTexParams`? I'm guessing that's not an ideal workaround.

Comment: I moved the content of my suggestions into your question and deleted my answer.  Hopefully that will make your question more visible since it has no answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone's looking for a solution for this, try [Joybox](http://joybox.io/). It's a wrapper for Cocos2D.

> Joybox combines the most popular and widely used 2D game engine for iOS, Cocos2D, folds in the amazing Box2D physics engine, and then wraps them up into a clean Ruby API that will make game development faster and more enjoyable for both beginners and experts alike.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a bridgesupport file generated for your framework. Please see:

https://github.com/MacRuby/MacRuby/wiki/MacRuby-Tutorial

and check out the "Accessing Static API's" section. That should point you in the right direction.